# How to deploy Spacy trained classification model on the file line by line?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

There are few examples of text classification with spacy by using textcat. Something like that

```
    def load_data(limit=0, split=0.8):
    train_data = train
    np.random.shuffle(train_data)
    train_data = train_data[-limit:]
    texts, labels = zip(*train_data)
    cats = [{'POSITIVE': bool(y)} for y in labels]
   split = int(len(train_data) * split)
    return (texts[:split], cats[:split]), (texts[split:], cats[split:])

 def evaluate(tokenizer, textcat, texts, cats):
docs = (tokenizer(text) for text in texts)
tp = 1e-8  # True positives
fp = 1e-8  # False positives
fn = 1e-8  # False negatives
tn = 1e-8  # True negatives
for i, doc in enumerate(textcat.pipe(docs)):
    gold = cats[i]
    for label, score in doc.cats.items():
        if label not in gold:
            continue
        if score >= 0.5 and gold[label] >= 0.5:
            tp += 1.
        elif score >= 0.5 and gold[label] < 0.5:
            fp += 1.
        elif score < 0.5 and gold[label] < 0.5:
            tn += 1
        elif score < 0.5 and gold[label] >= 0.5:
            fn += 1
precision = tp / (tp + fp)
recall = tp / (tp + fn)
f_score = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
return {'textcat_p': precision, 'textcat_r': recall, 'textcat_f': f_score}

#("Number of texts to train from","t" , int)
n_texts=8000
 #You can increase texts count if you have more computational power.

#("Number of training iterations", "n", int))
n_iter=3
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  # create english Language class
if 'textcat' not in nlp.pipe_names:
textcat = nlp.create_pipe('textcat')
nlp.add_pipe(textcat, last=True)
# otherwise, get it, so we can add labels to it
else:
textcat = nlp.get_pipe('textcat')

# add label to text classifier
textcat.add_label('POSITIVE')

 # load the dataset
  print("Loading food reviews data...")
 (train_texts, train_cats), (dev_texts, dev_cats) = 
  load_data(limit=n_texts)
 print("Using {} examples ({} training, {} evaluation)"
  .format(n_texts, len(train_texts), len(dev_texts)))
  train_data = list(zip(train_texts,
                  [{'cats': cats} for cats in train_cats]))
  other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'textcat']
  with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train textcat
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
print("Training the model...")
print('{:^5}\t{:^5}\t{:^5}\t{:^5}'.format('LOSS', 'P', 'R', 'F'))
for i in range(n_iter):
    losses = {}
    # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
    batches = minibatch(train_data, size=compounding(4., 32., 1.001))
    for batch in batches:
        texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
        nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.2,
                   losses=losses)
    with textcat.model.use_params(optimizer.averages):
        # evaluate on the dev data split off in load_data()
        scores = evaluate(nlp.tokenizer, textcat, dev_texts, dev_cats)
    print('{0:.3f}\t{1:.3f}\t{2:.3f}\t{3:.3f}'  # print a simple table
          .format(losses['textcat'], scores['textcat_p'],
                  scores['textcat_r'], scores['textcat_f']))
```

But all of them are finished by deploying trained model on piece of text, like that.

```
 test_text1 ='NEW YORK (Reuters) - Support for U.S. President Donald Trump 
 increased slightly among Republicans after he lashed out on Twitter over 
 the weekend'
 doc = nlp(test_text1)
 test_text1, doc.cats
  {'POSITIVE': 0.0011602493468672037})
```

I dont mind to deploy model on few pieces of text, but I have 300  pieces of text in csv file linewise and I am lazy:)
How  can I deploy model on csv file and get doc.cats for each line?

Answer (score 1):

When processing larger volumes of text, it's more efficient to use `docs = list(nlp.pipe(texts))` on a list of texts, instead of `doc = nlp(text)`. Or you can process them as a stream like so: `for doc in nlp.pipe(texts): ...`.

For more information, see [here](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#processing).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I check the link. Still I cannot figure it out how to practically write code

Comment: Thank you for your input @Sofie VL I checked the link. Still I cannot figure it out how to practically write code. May I kindly ask you to provide small piece of code for clarity.